# Change a string and insert characters in between

Tags: vb.net

I have this string: 71892378917238978
I want to do this: 71892-37891723-8978

I was trying this, but how i can do it multiple times?

```
String.Insert(6, "-")
```

Comment: Please explain what do you mean with _multiple times_

Comment: I want to be able to edit multiple points in a string / text

Comment: If you know how to do it once, surely you can do it twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could start with this idea. Create an array of the substrings that you want to exist between the dash symbol. In your expected string you have *71892-37891723-8978*, so the first block is composed of 5 char and the second block is 8 char.

Using the string.Substring method we could extract these substrings parts and store them in an array. Finally we could use string.Join to rebuild the string with the expected separator

```
Dim s As String = "71892378917238978"

' Define the substring blocks
Dim blocks As Integer() = New Integer() {5,8}
' Define the array that will contain the substrings
Dim substrings(blocks.Length) As String

' Get the blocks
For x As Integer = 0 To blocks.Length - 1
    substrings(x) = s.Substring(0,blocks(x))
    s = s.Substring(blocks(x))
Next

' Join together with the last part not included in the substrings
Dim result = String.Join("-", substrings) & s
Console.WriteLine(result)
```

You could generalize this code putting everything in a method where you could pass the string, the blocks and the separator.

Comment: Thank, but if i fry to use more than two numbers (5, 8, 10) i get errors

Comment: the numbers are the length of the substring blocks. if you have blocks of 5,8,10 length then you need a string with a total length of 23 characters